# Objective-C three-way comparison of identical values results to NO - why?

Tags: objective-c, comparison, boolean, equality

Considering that all three variables have identical values, one would expect the following comparison to result in YES:

```
NSUInteger count1 = 2;
NSUInteger count2 = 2;
NSUInteger count3 = 2;
BOOL countEqual = (count1 == count2 == count3);
// but: countEqual = NO
```

Alas countEqual is NO and I'd like to better understand why and whether this particular issue also appears in C or C++ code?

My guess is:

```
(count1 == count2) --> YES (1)
(YES == count3) or (1 == count3) --> NO (0)
```

Comment: This is a speed typing contest :)

Comment: LOL! There should be a "Lucky Luke" badge for answering a question within 10 seconds after it was posted! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other posters have already provided the answer, so I'll just quote the relevant part of the spec that confirms it:

> The `==` (equal to) and `!=` (not equal to) operators are analogous to the relational operators except for their lower precedence. Each of the operators yields 1 if the specified relation is true and 0 if it is false.

Equality is left associative, so it's interpreted as:

```
count1 == count2 == count3
(count1 == count2) == count3
(1) == count3
0
```

Answer (score 7):

Your guess is exactly correct, it will take the result from the first comparison, and compare it to the 3rd value. To do this you would need to do

`countEqual = (count1 == count2) && (count1 == count3);`

Answer (score 1):

Comparison operators such as `==` do not work like that in C and other C-like languages.

Change:

```
BOOL countEqual = (count1 == count2 == count3);
```

to:

```
BOOL countEqual = (count1 == count2 && count2 == count3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're guessing right. The result of the first comparison is compared to the third value. This is not what you want here.